# How to connect a client to a Symfony API to make OAuth2 authentication

Tags: symfony, oauth-2.0, api-platform.com

I am setting up an app made in React + php (symfony/API Platform), where react should use OAuth2 to authenticate the user on Facebook, but I am struggling to connect the frontend to the backend.

For now I am trying to make FB work. I installed [react-facebook-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-login), and configured it. I can see the authentication popup from FB, then I need to call my backend API to authenticate the user and save some info on my local db.

so, php side, I made a controller

```
class FacebookController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
    * @Route("/connect/facebook/check", name="connect_facebook_check")
    */
    public function connectCheckAction(Request $request, ClientRegistry $clientRegistry)
    {

    }

}
```

and an authenticator that extends KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Security\Authenticator\SocialAuthenticator

and configured it in security.yml:

```
guard:
    authenticators:
      - App\Security\Authenticator\FacebookAuthenticator
```

I can target the controller but I don't understand how to target this authenticator.
Also I am not sure if I am missing something... any help please?

I am following a tutorial [here](https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle) but I want to make a pure stateless API.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented JWT authentication in API platform, and I know that I indicate the authenticator like so, and it works:

```
//api/config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    providers:
        main:
            anonymous: true
            stateless: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

First guess: do you have the 'guard' key at the root level?  It should be nested within `security:providers:main` as in the tutorial.